# How to add stores to mobx-react Provider when they are dependent to each other?

Tags: dependency-injection, mobx, mobx-react

What is the best practice of initializing a store based on another one and put both of them in `Provider`?
I have a store called `AuthManager` it owns an observeable property called `user`. Also I have another store called `GoalManager`. I need the `user` property of `AuthManager` to initialize `GoalManager`.
I want to construct `GoalManager` like this:

```
const goalManager = new GoalManager(user);
```

But it is not possible to add something later in react's context because some children cannot update based on changes of context!
I solved this problem by sending `AuthManager` instance to `GoalManager`'s constructor, but I don't like it:

```
// services.js

const authManager = new AuthManager();
const goalManager = new GoalManager(authManager);

export default {
  authManager,
  goalManager
}
```

and later:

```
// index.jsx

import services from './services';

render(`
  <Provider {...services}>
    <App />
  </Provider>`, mountPoint);
```

I don't like this solution because I had to depend `GoalManager` to `AuthManager` but it only depends on `AuthManager.user`. Then testing `GoalManager` is  harder (because you have to mock a big object).

Is there any better solution for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe a completely other way of thinking, but this would solve your problem.

It looks like, this would work for you too:

```js
// AuthManager.js
class AuthManager {
  @observable user;
}

export default new AuthManager();
```

And just import AuthManager in GoalManager to use `AuthManger.user`

```js
// GoalManager.js

// import the AuthManager and use the user directly.
import AuthManager from './AuthManager'

class GoalManager {
  @computed get someThing() {
     if (AuthManager.user) {
       // your stuff..
     }
  }
}

export default new GoalManager();
```

in services you'll get the instances so.

```js
// services.js

import authManager from './AuthManager'
import goalManager from './GoalManager'

export default {
  authManager,
  goalManager
}
```

Do you got the idea?

Comment: how to mock `AuthManager` in case Im testing `GoalManager`?

Comment: what about server side rendering? you cannot use singletons because mobx instances would be shared between separate HTTP requests. Personally I solved this problem in the same way like in question, by injecting new instance into another store's constructor, but I am not 100% happy with it.

Comment: I wouldn't use mobx on the server for rendering, it's client-side-fancy reaction lib, the key point of mobx is to have reactive runtime, not initial data  loading.. I would say..